# Do I use the Paint event to position controls at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, resize, controls

I am fairly new to C# programming coming from VB6 so please be gentle :P

I have been using Panels to group controls (i.e. Panels contains Textbox, Labels, Listview, etc.) and then have the panel align itself at run-time so that the controls align in different resolutions.  However, I am doing this from the Panel's Paint routine(?)

i.e.:

```
private void pnlTop_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        btnExit.Location                = new Point(this.Width - (this.Left + lblTitleMain.Left + btnExit.Width), 10);
        btnMinimize.Location            = new Point(this.Width - (this.Left + lblTitleMain.Left + (btnExit.Width * 2)), 10);
        btnSettings.Location            = new Point(this.Width - (this.Left + lblTitleMain.Left + (btnExit.Width * 2 + btnExit.Width)), 10);

        lblTitleMain.Left               = (((this.ClientSize.Width - lblTitleMain.Width) / 2) / 2) / 2;
        lblTitleMain.Top                = btnExit.Top + lblTitleMain.Height;

        int intMenuY                    = lblTitleMain.Bottom + 5;
        lnkMenuSystem.Location          = new Point(lblTitleMain.Left + 3, intMenuY);
        lnkMenuDeployment.Location      = new Point(lnkMenuSystem.Right + 50, intMenuY);
        lnkMenuTables.Location          = new Point(lnkMenuDeployment.Right + 50, intMenuY);
        lnkMenuTCP.Location             = new Point(lnkMenuTables.Right + 50, intMenuY);
        lnkMenuDCM.Location             = new Point(lnkMenuTCP.Right + 50, intMenuY);
        lnkMenuProcessData.Location     = new Point(lnkMenuDCM.Right + 50, intMenuY);
        lnkMenuGenerateReports.Location = new Point(lnkMenuProcessData.Right + 50, intMenuY);

        lineMenuButtom.StartPoint       = new Point((((this.ClientSize.Width - lblTitleMain.Width) / 2) / 2) / 2, lnkMenuSystem.Top + lnkMenuSystem.Height + 10);
        lineMenuButtom.EndPoint         = new Point(this.Width - (this.Left + lblTitleMain.Left), lnkMenuSystem.Top + lnkMenuSystem.Height + 10);

        lnkMenuErrorMessage.Location    = new Point(lnkMenuSystem.Left, lineMenuButtom.Y1+5);
        lnkMessageWelcome.Location      = new Point(lineMenuButtom.X2 - lnkMessageWelcome.Width, lineMenuButtom.Y2 + 5);
        GlobalVariables.intGeneralLeft  = lineMenuButtom.StartPoint.X;
        GlobalVariables.intGeneralWidth = lineMenuButtom.X2;
    }
```

What I want to ask is this:  **Is this the proper way to do it?**

The reason for this was because I am uncertain if this will impact performance once the application runs on old systems (assuming that it would be used in XP with 2g RAM Pentium 4 HT or equivalent System).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No; that is certainly the wrong way to do it.
`Paint` can fire very often; you should do as little work in it as possible.  (and you certainly shouldn't modify the layout)

Instead, you should set the `Anchor` and `Dock` properties in the designer so that it will all happen automatically.

Comment: Agreed about using `Anchor` and `Dock` if possible. These weren't in VB 6 and make your life in WinForms a *whole* lot easier. Otherwise, handle the [`Layout` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.layout.aspx) for the panel control.

Comment: @CodyGray: Better yet: Otherwise, use WPF.

Comment: @SLaks: Thank you for the answer and suggestion.  I have noticed a significant "hicup" in the application indeed during run-time when the `paint` Method fires.  Thank you very much.

On the subject of WPF however, I am a bit intimidated with it since I have zero experience with it and looking at it is a bit daunting.  I'll use it if there is no more option or if I garner more experience.